# Distribute Python packages on all the executor nodes in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am following the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html) to create tar.gz and distribute it to all the executors.

```bash
python -m venv pyspark_venv
source test_env/bin/activate
pip install quote venv-pack
venv-pack -o test_env.tar.gz
```

And after that I upload the tar file to master node using SCP and run spark-submit

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--archives test_env.tar.gz#environment \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python \
app_venv.py
```

I also set the Python configuration using export in spark-env file. But the spark-submit throws below error.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./environment/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I cannot install the packages manually on all the nodes because we have spot nodes on EMR.

Comment: Have you tried to configure [Bootstrap actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html) for the cluster nodes?

Comment: Can you confirm that you can use python command in master node? python path may be wrong or filename can be python3??

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I think bootstrap actions can only be defined while creating the cluster. "You can create custom bootstrap actions and specify them when you create your cluster."

Comment: @ozlemg Yes, I can run Python command on master node. I can install Python package on master node and launch my driver on master node, that lets me use python packages. Issue happens when I use packages inside UDFs, because that requires packages on executor nodes.

Comment: make sure the python path is correct -- `./environment/bin/python` is the path called out in the error trace

Comment: @SanketSanath The guide says not to set `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` in cluster mode. Can you try that?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I tried by not setting `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` in cluster mode. But it didn't fix anything.